# Issue with modifying property of a spring bean with default scope - singleton

Tags: spring

I've a simple spring bean/component with one method and one int property (initialized to 0) as shown below and this method (Kafka consumer) is being called multiple times in a short span of time.

```
@Component
public class MyKafkaConsumer{

    public int messageCount = 0;

    @KafkaListener
    public void consumeMessage(MyPayload payload){
        messageCount++;
        System.out.println("messageCount - "+ messageCount);
    } 
}
```

Now when I see the output of this method, it's coming as below and I'm surprised to see this output.

```
messageCount - 1
messageCount - 2
messageCount - 3
messageCount - 4
messageCount - 1
messageCount - 2
```

...

Here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "mypackages"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("MyApplication is ready........");
    }
}
```

This behavior is not consistent but intermittent. Can someone help me understand why is it behaving like this? Am i missing something basic here?

I tried with synchronized block as shown below

```
@Component
public class MyKafkaConsumer{

    public int messageCount = 0;

    @KafkaListener
    public void consumeMessage(MyPayload payload){
        System.out.println("Thread - "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" count "+messageCount);
        
        synchronized (this){
            messageCount++;
        }
    } 
}
```

and here is the output and we can clearly see there is only one thread operating there and the count is expected to be 7 for but it's not

```
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 0
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 1
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 2
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 5
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 3
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 4
Thread - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 count 5
```

Comment: Make the field `volatile` or use an `AtomicInteger`. Or don't modify shared state. Also are you really sure it is a singleton?

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I tried all those options but didn't work because it's not multi-threading issue. It is a singleton for sure because spring bean's default scope is singleton.

Comment: Unless you have component scanning and an `@Bean` method you get multiple instances. So depending on your configuration it might not be a singleton. If you tried those options you are reloading the configuration or loading the config multiple times and get a fresh instance of the class. So please show your configuration. I would also suggest using a logger instead of `System.out` which gives you thread and instance information for the logging.

Comment: i tried printing the instance and I'm sure its the same instance for all the calls

Comment: Again please add the additional configuration. I doubt it is the same instance or else it is a multi threading issue. If it is none of those you aren't showing use the actual problematic code but some dummed down version. So again please provide the requested additional information.

Comment: Please edit the question don't add it as comments that is totally unreadable.

Comment: done, added the config

Comment: That is the bootstrapping, there must be more for the kafka part like settings in your `application.properties` maybe an additional `@Configuration` class. The fact that you have an `@ComponentScan` is also interesting, generally that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: sure, I've application.properties for kafka but they don't define how your spring bean is created. We use the @EnableKafka annotation which will do the background magic of detecting of 'KafkaListener' annotations on any spring-managed bean in the container. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafka.html

Comment: I'm quite sure this is multithread issue, you can try enclosing the two statements in `consumeMessage` with synchronized block to see.

Comment: @samabcde : Thanks for the response. I'm i've tried it but didn't work because there are no multiple threads here.... but  let me try it again and make sure i didn't miss this.

Comment: @samabcde - I've updated the code to add synchronized block per your suggestion and you can see the output.. it's the same behavior.

Comment: @M. Deinum - Let me know if I am missing anything here or can I provide any other inputs

Comment: The annotation isn't even correct. So I highly doubt that the code you show is the actual code, next to that I would still suggest to use a logger and not system.out, depending on how things are run it might even be async and out of order. I know what `@EnableKafka` does and with Spring Boot you shouldn't even need it (it even will disable parts of the auto configuration provided by Spring Boot.